# Matching string format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How is it possible to perform a matching of string, just like `regex`?

For example i have an array of strings, I want to match if these string is in the format of `"abc def xxx"`, which `xxx` is number like `1`, `11`, `12`, `100`, `111`, etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The arrays:**

```
NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc def 1", @"abc def 64", @"abc def 853", @"abc def 14", nil];
NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc def 3", @"abc def 856", @"abc def 36", @"abc def 5367", nil];
```

**The regular expression:**

```
NSString *regex = @"abc def [0-9]{1,3}";
```

**To check if all strings in the array matche the regex:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL description MATCHES %@", regex];
BOOL allStringsMatch = [predicate evaluateWithObject:array1]; 
// OUTPUT: YES
allStringsMatch = [predicate evaluateWithObject:array2];
// OUTPUT: NO
```

All objects in *array1* matches the regex, but *array2* contains the string *@"abc def 5367"* which doesn't match the regex.

**To get the matched strings:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"description MATCHES %@", regex];
NSArray *unmatchedStrings = [array2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
// OUTPUT: { @"abc def 3", @"abc def 856", @"abc def 36" }
```

**To get the unmatched strings:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT description MATCHES %@", regex];
NSArray *unmatchedStrings = [array2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
// OUTPUT: { @"abc def 5367" }
```

Note that here *"description"* in predicate is the *`- description`* method of *NSString*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NSRegularExpression Class, take a look at that!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html